# Evaluate the integral of the given contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm being asked to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{z^3(z^2+1)}dz$, where C is the circle $\lvert z-1 \rvert=\frac32$

I started by determining the zeroes, which are $0, -i, \,i$ Then I applied the Cauchy Integral Formula but it is here where Im not sure if i am applying it correctly.

I took $\int \frac{1}{z^3(z^2+1)}dz$

$=\int \frac{1}{z^3(z^2+1)}dz$+$\int \frac{1}{z^3(z^2+1)}dz$+$\int \frac{1}{z^3(z^2+1)}dz$

$=2\pi i+2\pi i+2\pi i$

$=6\pi i$

Is this application correct? If not, could someone please explain to me how to do this properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the integrand has poles in the interior of $C$, you could  use the residue theorem or Cauchy's integral theorem instead. I think using the residue theorem would be easier.

If, however, you insist on using Cauchy's formula, write
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^3 (z^2 + 1)} = \int_C \frac{dz}{z^3 (z - i)(z + i)}.$$
By the Cauchy-Goursat theorem,
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^3 (z^2 + 1)} = \int_{C_1} \frac{(z - i)^{-1} (z + i)^{-1}}{z^3} dz + \int_{C_2} \frac{z^{-3} (z + i)^{-1}}{z - i} dz + \int_{C_3} \frac{z^{-3} (z - i)^{-1}}{z + i} dz,$$
where $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, with $C_i \cap C_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \ne j$, are small circular contours around $0$, $i$, $-i$, respectively. Now, the last two integrals can be evaluated directly using Cuachy's formula. The first one, however, cannot, so you need to use Cuachy's generalized integral formula.

Alternatively, since
$$\frac{1}{z^3 (z - i)(z + i)} = \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{2(z - i)} + \frac{1}{2(z + i)} - \frac{1}{z} \tag{$\ast$}$$
and $0$, $i$, $-i$ are inside $C$,
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{2(z - i)} + \int_C \frac{dz}{2(z + i)} - \int_C \frac{dz}{z}$$
can be evaluated using Cuachy's formula. Yet, $\int_{C} z^{-3} dz$ requires Cuachy's generalized integral formula.

Comment: well, using that theorem, that would meant that this equal 0???

Comment: Not necessarily. There are poles in the interior of $C$, so the integral is not necessarily zero.

Comment: @cele I edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the edit. Im still looking it over, trying to make sense of it. Towards the end, for the first integral, were you doing partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: I'm not sure where $\frac{1}{z^3 (z - i)(z + i)} = \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{2(z - i)} + \frac{1}{2(z + i)} - \frac{1}{z}$ comes from. When I solve it, I get something slightly different

Comment: would it be $4\pi i???$

Comment: @cele The partial fraction decomposition in $(\ast)$ is correct. You are not suppose to solve anything. You need to decompose the right-hand side of $(\ast)$ into partial fractions. I practically gave you the answer. You just need to use Cauchy's formula.

Comment: Ok, taking what you gave you, I worked it out and got $\frac 13\pi i$ as my answer. I hope this is correct